# Buffer Overflow character parsing

Tags: perl, buffer, overflow

When I was trying to do a proof of concept for a buffer overflow, I came across an odd issue.  There existed code in the program that I wanted to execute at address **0x0828433c**.  It was a simple overflow, so the attack was executed as so:

`$ perl -e 'system("./program lotsofcharacterstofillinspacethen\x3c\x43\x28\x08")'`

However, the `\x3c` goes to > in ascii, and the shell expected the rest of the characters to be an output file. (ie. `echo 1 > hello.txt` )

Luckily there were 2 nops above it, so I didn't need to use that specific address, but what if I had needed to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Use the multi-argument version of [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html), which doesn't invoke a shell:

   ```
   system "./program", "lotsofcharacterstofillinspacethen\x3c\x43\x28\x08";
   ```
2. [Escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212128/perl-equivalent-of-phps-escapeshellarg) any shell metacharacters in the argument, e.g. using [String::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String::ShellQuote).