# Perl script to stop bsub job when control c is pressed

Tags: perl, control-c

I am running a perl script which internally launches bsub jobs . I wanted to kill all jobs launched by this perl script when control c is pressed in unix terminal when i run the perl script based on the group id .

Please advise.

Thanks & Regards
amrutha

---

*Edit: code copied from a comment*

```
my $command = "bsub -q normal -g GROUPID <command>";

system($command);
```

Comment: Can send `kill` to whatever processes need be terminated from the signal handler (or use a module for process management). Can you show how you launch jobs and what they are?

Comment: I assign my $command = "bsub -q normal -g GROUPID <command>";
system($command);

Comment: Thank you but please edit the question to add that to it.  Further detail would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to send `SIGTERM` via [kill](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html) to the process group from the signal handler for Ctrl-C

```
$SIG{INT} = sub { kill 15, -$gpid };  # $gpid used in bsub command
```

Whether this will work, and how reliably, depends on many details of what those jobs are and do.

An example of how a process can (unknowingly) dodge the bullet is seen below, where the child process changes its process group ID. It does this for a demo of signalling the group but then that also demonstrates a loophole in signalling the group.

An example

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $pid;

$SIG{INT} = sub { 
    say "Got $_[0]. Send TERM to process group with $pid"; 
    kill 15, -$pid;
}; 

$pid = fork // die "Can't fork: $!";

if ($pid == 0) {
    $SIG{INT} = 'IGNORE';
    setpgrp 0, $$;
    say "\tChild's process group: ", getpgrp;
    sleep 10; 
    say "\tkid done"; 
    exit;
}; 

say "Parent $$ started $pid";

sleep 5; 
sleep 3;   # return to sleep after signal is handled

say "done";
```

When `kill` is sent  to a negated PID (or with a negative signal) it goes to that process group. Here I use the child's `$pid` (to be assigned) and in the child set its group id to that (`$$`).

The signal has to be dealt with in the child as well since the forked process inherits the handler.

With Ctrl-C pressed after a few seconds the output is

```
Parent 10450 started 10451
        Child's process group: 10451
^CGot INT. Send TERM to group 10451
done
```

where `done` is printed 3 seconds after the previous prints. The `kid done` never comes.

If you want the parent to terminate as well add an `exit` or such to the signal handler.

As noted, this may fail, for one thing since the child can simply change its group. A more reliable way would be to catalog jobs that may get triggered and then find their PIDs at runtime, so to terminate them. A useful tool for this is [Proc::ProcessTable](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/DURIST/Proc-ProcessTable-0.39/ProcessTable.pm). Some examples of hunting down processes are in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49380136/4653379) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43796534/4653379).