# perl open() always returns the PID of the sh instead of the underlying program

Tags: perl, perl-io, perl-ipc-run

I have to kill a program that I am opening via

`$pid = open(FH, "program|")`

or

`$pid = or open(FH, "-|", "program")`

However, the program (mosquittto_sub, to be specific) still lingers around in the background, because `open` is returning the PID of the `sh` that perl is using to run the program, so I am only killing the `sh` wrapper instead of the actual program.

Is there a way to get the programs real PID? What is the point of getting the `sh`'s PID?

Comment: Are you using `kill` on `pid` or `close` on `FH`?

Comment: ```kill``` on ```$pid```, because the sub program hangs/blocks upon close. So I have to kill it manually instead of just calling ```close```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few ways to deal with this.

First, you can **use a *list form*** to [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) a process and then no shell is involved so the child process (with pid returned by `open`) is precisely the one with the program you need to stop

```
my @cmd = ('progname', '-arg1', ...);

my $pid = open my $fh, '-|', @cmd  // die "Can't open \"@cmd\": $!";

...

my $num_signaled = kill 15, $pid;
```

This sketch needs some checks added.  Please see the linked documentation (look for "pipe").

If this isn't suitable for some reason -- perhaps you *need* the shell to run that program -- then you can **find the program's pid**,  and [Proc::ProcessTable](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/DURIST/Proc-ProcessTable-0.39/ProcessTable.pm) module is good for this.  A basic demo

```
use Proc::ProcessTable;

my $prog_name = ...

my $pid;
my $pt = Proc::ProcessTable->new();

foreach my $proc (@{$pt->table}) {
    if ($proc->cmndline =~ /\Q$prog_name/) {  # is this enough to identify it?
        $pid = $proc->pid;
        last;
    }   
}
my $num_signaled = kill 15, $pid;
```

Please be careful with identifying the program by its name -- on a modern system there may be all kinds of processes running that contain the name of the program you want to terminate.  For more detail and discussion please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49380136/4653379) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43796534/4653379), for starters.

Finally, you can **use a module to run your external programs** and then you'll be able to manage and control them far more nicely. Here I'd recommend [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run).

Comment: Note that using the list form does not guarantee no shell in Windows.

Comment: I went the command-args-as-list approach, and it worked great. Also explains why ```open()``` was calling ```sh``` - to handle command line arg processing.